# Get a:hover font color to work for the full li box

Tags: html, css

How can I get the `a:hover` font color to be `#fff` when the entire `li` box is hovered over and not just the `href` link? Right now, the `li` hover color flickers between `#fff` and `#666` on hover because the full `li` box is not a link.

*If it matters, this html is generated by the Google RSS widget and Google's stylesheet is at http://www.google.com/uds/api/feeds/1.0/482f2817cdf8982edf2e5669f9e3a627/default+en.css , but there doesn't appear (to me, at least) to be any conflicts there.*

```css
#my-feed {width:180px;}
#rss-title {font-size:12px; color:#fff; text-align:center; padding:3px; background-color: #cc6600;}
#rss-title a {color:#fff;}

#rss-feed li {
list-style: inside none none;
font-size:12px;
padding:5px 5px 5px 20px;
line-height:14px;
text-indent: -10px;
}

#rss-feed li a {color:#666;}
#rss-feed li a:hover {color:#fff;}
#rss-feed li:hover {color:#fff;background-color:#cc6600;}
#my-feed ul li:before { content: "\00BB \0020";}
```

```html
<div id="my-feed">
<div id="rss-title">
<a href="http://example.com">My Title</a>
</div>

<ul id="rss-feed">
<li><a href="http://example.com/first">My First Link</a></li>

<li><a href="http://example.com/second">My Second Link</a></li>

<li><a href="http://example.com/third">My Third Link</a></li>

<li><a href="http://example.com/fourth">My Fourth Link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `#rss-feed li a:hover {color:#fff;}`, use `#rss-feed li:hover a {color:#fff;}`

```css
#my-feed {width:180px;}
#rss-title {font-size:12px; color:#fff; text-align:center; padding:3px; background-color: #cc6600;}
#rss-title a {color:#fff;}

#rss-feed li {
list-style: inside none none;
font-size:12px;
padding:5px 5px 5px 20px;
line-height:14px;
text-indent: -10px;
}

#rss-feed li a {color:#666;}
#rss-feed li:hover a {color:#fff;}
#rss-feed li:hover {color:#fff;background-color:#cc6600;}
#my-feed ul li:before { content: "\00BB \0020";}
```

```html
<div id="my-feed">
<div id="rss-title">
<a href="http://example.com">My Title</a>
</div>

<ul id="rss-feed">
<li><a href="http://example.com/first">My First Link</a></li>

<li><a href="http://example.com/second">My Second Link</a></li>

<li><a href="http://example.com/third">My Third Link</a></li>

<li><a href="http://example.com/fourth">My Fourth Link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, that was easy. Thanks!